# Kafka leader election

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

My application produces data to Kafka and uses Zookeeper to do leader election. Now that Kafka won't be needing Zookeeper anymore, I need to move away from it too, because I don't want to keep it in my infrastructure just for that.
So, does Kafka provide an API to achieve leader election? Or I would have to do it manually, creating a topic and coming up with my own logic?
My application have many instances but only one of them should produce to Kafka at the same time, so I need a kind of distributed lock and I was hoping to do it in an easy way using Kafka itself or k8s, avoiding have to add another piece to my infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now that Kafka won't be needing Zookeeper anymore ... does Kafka provide an API to achieve leader election

It will use a [Raft protocol internal to the brokers](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/kraft/README.md), yes,

I doubt it is intended to be multi-purpose for external usage, like Zookeeper.

> distributed lock ... k8s

[You could use etcd](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/tutorials/how-to-create-locks/)