# Kafka consumer poll

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using a topic with only one partition and consumer groups to simulate a distributed lock. Active instance publishes heartbeats there, and passive instance consumes them and become active when no more heartbeats have been sent in a while.

The topic has retention.ms=5min and segment.ms=5min, and the consumer has auto.offset.reset=earliest, enable.auto.commit=false, max.poll.records=150000.

Offsets are never committed. I want the consumer to get all data in the topic on each poll. The problem is that sometimes the poll does not return all data in the topic.

In which conditions can the poll do that, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you invoke `consumer.seekToBeginning()` or restart the consumer with `auto.offset.reset=earliest` & `enable.auto.commit=false`, then each poll will start at the following offset marker from the previous batch while that consumer process is active.

Zookeeper might be a better option for a distributed lock, and it is a well-documented pattern. Or [as mentioned before, etcd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73900994/2308683).

If you are using a single topic to maintain some state, then only one consumer of any group can read that data, anyway. To query data from the topic, you could build a KTable and implement Interactive Queries.